# PHP PDO Return Column Value From Row By Index

Tags: php, sql, pdo, indexing

I have written this code:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT answer FROM question WHERE question = :question");
$statement->execute(array(':question' => $question));
$row = $statement->fetch();
$answer = $row['answer']; // this gives me a number
```

Now i want to retrieve the value from that row from the column (the number given)+1

What should i do to get that?

Comment: `$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: Depending on the order of columns seems like a dangerous way to code. Do the columns have names like `answer1`, `answer2`, etc.?

Comment: Not quiet, they all ahve different names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select all fields (`SELECT * FROM...`) and use `$row[$answer + 1]`:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM question WHERE question = :question");
$statement->execute(array(':question' => $question));
$row = $statement->fetch();
$answer = $row['answer'];
$other = $row[$answer + 1];
```

Comment: Right, assuming you `fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)`.